# YQL returning table of undefined values, even though JSON object has contents

Tags: json, google-docs, yql

I'm using Google Docs and YQL to power a job postings board. I got one version up and running at

http://jsfiddle.net/N4Hb8/8/ .

Then I modified the YQL query to only get jobs listed as "open", which returns this JSON object:

http://bit.ly/i0phfc

But the resulting table is full of "undefined"'s.

http://jsfiddle.net/N4Hb8/10/

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to have gone wrong is that in your first example, `item` is an actual object, whereas in your second example, `item` actually refers to the columns you want. If you `console.log(item)` you'll see what I mean.

More specifically, it appears that in your first example, it happens to return an array of results. In your second example, it returns a single result.

To fix your code, you'll need to handle the special case that you're returned only one item.

Comment: oh, ok. I appreciate your help!